# Can a psion manifest an unknown power exclusive to another discipline?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Two [psions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/psion.htm)—a kineticist and an egoist—are trapped in the rubble of a collapsed building. They're allies sharing the same air pocket. The kineticist doesn't have any powers that allow him to escape, but the egoist has the power [*ectoplasmic form*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/ectoplasmicForm.htm), which is *Range: Personal* and *Target: You*.

The egoist wants to help his buddy, so the egoist suggests that the kineticist try to manifest *ectoplasmic form* using the [specific rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#manifestAnUnknownPowerFromAnothersPowersKnown) for doing so.

*Except* it seems like  the egoist will have to think of another way to help his friend as the kineticist will fail because the power *ectoplasmic form* must be on the potential manifester's power list.

Is that correct? Or can the kineticist go ahead and borrow that power?

Answer (score 4):

**He can't use the power.**

The important line is:

> Next, the psionic character must choose one of the powers and make a
>   second Psicraft check (DC 15 + the power’s level) to see if he
>   understands it. If the power is not on his class list, he
>   automatically fails this check.

The 'Manifesting an Unknown Power' ability is purely for making use of a Psionic Power that is on your class list but that your character hasn't actually learnt.